# Cannot populate other drop down menus with other values- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I seem to have a problem with Javascript. I am currently trying to use arrays to populate dropdown menus. They are dynamically appearing drop down menus. In my example, the countries and cities and activites are populating correctly for USA. However, for Canada and UK, the activities list is still using the USA's activities list. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? If what I just explained seems a bit confusing, please take a look at the jsfiddle I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/KCz3G/

```
<title>Page Title</title>
```

Comment: like, I click on USA, then a city, and the next dropdown menu populates itself with the correct array of activities

but Canada and UK's activities list still use USA's activities arrays.

Comment: can you tell/help me please? I'm really frustrated at this.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean, so how would I correct it?

Comment: the problem is that the other functions which make the dropdown menu dynamically appear rely on an array to store the items.

Comment: so doing what you said would need for me to completely rewrite the code

Comment: okeydokey. How would I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this as a start to store the data, things might get easier:

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KCz3G/3/

```
var cities = {
 usa: ['New York|newyorkvalue', ...],
 uk: ['London|londonvalue', ...]
};

var activities = {
 newyorkvalue: ['xxx|yyy', ...],
 londonvalue: ['xxx|yyy', ...]
};

//get cities in usa
for (i=0;i<cities["usa"].length;i++) {

}
```

Which mean you use/pass the "value text", like `londonvalue` as a parameter instead of an `index` to find which array of "something" to populate.

It will give you much more flexibility, still using arrays of values.

Comment: will this affect the other functions in the code, particularly updatecities and updateactivites?

Comment: hmmm, how would I do that? Sorry about the questions, my mind is really shot right now. And do I need that for loop?

Comment: okay, so this is what I have on my jsfiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/KCz3G/

you said to use the text value, by that, you mean take out objIndex?

Comment: all I see changed is this value: objIndex = y.options[y.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: I am trying to teach/show you how to do it, so you can understand what it does. Anything else will be "doing it for you" which will not help in the long run. Take your time going through yours and mine, step by step, and see what it does, and as soon you see that, it will be a piece of cake to both do it and even optimize it yourself.

Comment: I changed the arrays to the object, but I still don't see it. Thank you so much for your help by the way.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand, where in your demo did you change 'objIndex' from type index to type 'text'?

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHH! I am such a derp. Thank you so much! :D All the internet points to you sir!

Comment: Hi there! So all the problems I had are all fixed, I just have one issue left. How do I print out the choices the user made onto the screen? For example, if the user chose Marvel, Avengers and Iron Man, I would have the script print out "You chose Marvel, the Avengers, and Iron Man." I can't use innerHTML.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page or some code as it is now, and I will figure it out

Comment: You collect the items while people do the selects, and then you add them to the screen as with any other text you add, like the form text in the end.

Comment: oh woops sorry got it